# change keyboard value

Tags: keyboard

My nephew played with my keyboard and now my S key is out. Is there a way I can change the keyboard layout to attribute the S value to a key I don't use (ie, right Alt)? To make myself crystal clear, is there a way that I can tell Ubuntu that when I press the right Alt, it prints S?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a line to the .xinitrc file in your home folder, or add a command to your startup scripts. This command will remap your keyboard to use a different key for "s".

The command you have to add will look something like this: `xmodmap -e 'keycode <value>=<action>'`. You have to replace "value" with the key you will press to represent "action" letter. For example, in your case, you want to reassign the letter E to the right Alt key (a guide for all the different key codes is [here](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/)). I don't know how to assign S to the right Alt key but the Left Alt key is no problem. Make a command like this: `xmodmap -e 'keycode 64=s'` and add it to your startup scripts.

Comment: yeah! it worked! The value for Alt-Right did not show in the link you hit me, but after some google, you can just type `xmodmap` from tty with no args and it will show you special codes for your keyboard. This is what worked for me:
`xmodmap -e 'keycode 0x6c=s'`

Answer (score 1):

Try xkeycaps (you may have to install the package, not sure).
This suggestion comes from [an old forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1164673)

Comment: the gui is very old school, so I went for solution above but i'll definitely give it a closer look when i'll have the time ;)