# Function Keys the wrong way around on Packard Bell Dot S

Tags: keyboard

I have a Packard Bell Dot S netbook (also called Dot 510 I think), and to get an F3 key press I have to press Fn+F3, pressing just F3 on its own turns the wireless on or off. I make heavy use of the F Keys, so I'd like it if I didn't have to use the Fn key to get them.

My BIOS doesn't seem to have an option to swap them round, is there any way I can do it at the OS Level in Ubuntu?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

FWIW here is what is in my bios:

InsydeH20 Setup Utility Rev 3.5

Information:

- CPU type.speed, memory info etc etc

Main:

- Time, Date, Quiet Boot, Network Boot, F12 Boot Menu, D2D Recovery, SATA Mode

Security:

- Set Supervisor Password, Set User password, Set HDD password

Boot:

- Boot Order stuff

Exit:

- Saving Changes etc etc

Unless there is a hidden page? I recall a BIOS from years ago that had a hidden page. Googling shows nothing tho.

**Update 2**

Ok, it seems that xmodmad will only work for some keys. The wireless switch key, for example, works even when X is not running, so it must be at a lower level that it is being intercepted. I can't even get the keycodes for this key.

Comment: @fossfreedom See my update...

Comment: Quite likely keytouch will do what you need:

http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/

If not you can also try xkeyboard. Give them a whirl and see what happens

Comment: @DaedalusFall - what version of ubuntu are you using - also can you also try adding "acpi_osi=Linux" as a grub boot option?

Comment: ... @DaedalusFall - also - what version of your BIOS are you using - it seems 1.16 exists for DOT S... I cant find any release notes but maybe such a keyboard option would have been added in the latest update?

Comment: 1.16 that I can find says it is not for my netbook. I'll try updating the BIOS if I can find the right one tho.

Answer (score 1):

You may try remapping your keyboard like they did in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89769/change-keyboard-value/89777#89777) thread. You can use the gui tool xmodmaps to find out the information you need. The command you will most likely need is `xmodmap -e 'keycode 69=F3'` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on **Dot SC**, but it seems that Packard Bell corrected its mistake and finally included in **BIOS setup** an option to restore normal Function Keys behavior (BIOS **ver. 1.9** dated 2012-10-23).

Answer (score 0):

From the (un)help file on the HP laptop:

Note: It is not necessary to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to use the <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> function keys when starting your computer or when using the BIOS.

To swap the hotkey and special function of the <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> keys, change the function key setting in the BIOS (to open the BIOS press <kbd>F2</kbd> when starting your computer, then select the Main menu and change Function key behavior to
Function keys).

Comment: As I have already stated there is no such option in by BIOS.

Comment: Although it does indeed say that in my real physical paper laptop manual. Definately not in the bios tho.