# Disable fn functions on keyboard

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T540p) with dualboot Windows and Ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. I need to make frequent use of the F keys (F1 through F12), but I must always press in the combination `fn + F1-F12` and it's getting annoying.

This happens only on Ubuntu so I'm guessing there should be a setting in Ubuntu which I can modify. I have tried the two solutions from [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89769/change-keyboard-value/89777#89777) but I don't have a `.xinitrc` file and `xkeycaps` doesn't do the trick.

I have also tried [the Solaar answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285512/how-to-change-function-fn-key-behavior-on-wireless-logitech-keyboard?rq=1) but it doesn't show any device..

In short: F1 mutes my sound while Fn + F1 brings up the help and I want it the other way around

--Edit April 14

I have included a screenshot of my bios with the available options for keyboard/mouse

[image: BIOS Screenshot]

As you can see: I only have three available options.

Comment: You could boot a live cd of the 14.04 beta just to see if the hardware support is better.

Comment: This is a work pc so I would rather not migrate to a beta

Comment: I was not suggesting to migrate but to try a live cd, btw could you add to your question the point release you're using? 12.04.4?

Comment: Added the point release, it's indeed 12.04.4

Comment: 14.04 will be out soon (two weeks from tomorrow) it might be worth a try (on a liveCD that is).

Answer (score 1):

In my Lenovo G500 and there's a setting in the BIOS for this - see the screenshot below. If you don't have this you may need to update your BIOS from [here](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?DocID=DS038147). It's dated March 2014 so it's pretty recent (this is for Win 8.1). You can see from the description in the screenshot that it does exactly what you want.

[image: BIOS page showing hotkey mode enable/disable]

Comment: But wouldn't this change the behaviour on Windows since it works there correctly?

Comment: That didn't work because I don't have those options. I've included a screenshot of my bios setup

Comment: What BIOS Version are you running? Unfortunately there's little info about what the differences are but it might be worth upgrading.

Comment: GMET31WW (1.11 ) is my BIOS version

Comment: From the link in my answer above you can download the latest version, V2.10 (GMET62WW). I don't know if this will add the functionality you need but IMO it is not a bad idea to use the latest version. You are four versions behind the latest, which was only released less than a month ago (27th March). Be sure to view the associated readme file.